# SQL Express 2008 uninstall not complete

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I get rid of SQL Express 2008 after it's been uninstalled. It's all over my file system and all over the registry on 2008 R2 server sp1.

Answer (score 0):

- Was the uninstall completed successfully?
- Are you sure there are no other components installed for SQL Server? (Have a look at Control Panel -> Programs and Features)

If you are sure that both hold true, then I would just *delete* those entries.